# Error - The class 'javax.persistence.Entity' is required to be in the selected libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

We use the OpenJPA 2.0.0 as a JPA provider. We created the user library and added the openjpa-2.0.0 jar. But the IDE (Eclipse) shows the error "The class 'javax.persistence.Entity' is required to be in the selected libraries".

Note: Currently we maintain the openjpa-2.0.0 jar within the workspace (within Repo folder).

If we move the Repo folder outside of the workspce we don't get any errors.

Can anyone please suggest why this is happening?

Comment: try to add into your libraries org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.0